# Show single instance of form in other project

Tags: vb.net

I have multiproject solution where one project is "main", startup project.
From this project I starting forms in other projects which all are referenced in startup project.

Problem is that I can start those forms as instances like this:

```
    Dim ka As New otherproject.frm_thatform
    With ka
        .BringToFront()
        .Show(Me)
    End With
```

That opens new "thatform" every time but I would like to to start "thatform" like single instance every time and that "thatform" comes to front.

How to do that?

I try like this:

```
Dim ka As otherproject.frm_thatform
With ka
    .BringToFront()
    .Show(Me)
End With
```

... but that don't work (Object reference not set to an instance of an object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to not Dim the form and use it as a Shared object.

```
Otherproject.frm_thatform.Show()
Otherproject.frm_thatform.BringToFront()
```

As long as you dont close this window you can call it the same way as a Dimmed object.

Instead of ka you just type Otherproject.frm_thatform

As soon as you close the window it will loose everything in it.

EDIT: Apparently this only works with forms inside the project. My bad :(

What you need to do instead is keep a list of Forms inside your main project.

Make sure you give the form a name, and when you click the button to open the form simply loop through the list to find the set name.

Something like this:

```
 Private FormList As New List(Of Form)
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim theForm As Form = Nothing
    For Each f As Form In FormList
        If f.Name = "Selected form name" Then
            theForm = f
        End If
    Next
    If theForm Is Nothing Then
        theForm = New Otherproject.frm_thatform()
        theForm.Name = "Selected form name"
        FormList.Add(theForm)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi WozzeC, something is still missing. I get error "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference". Should I make Otherproject.frm_thatform SHARED somehow?

Comment: As far as I know it should be enough with Public Class frm_thatForm. But I'll make a test with cross project forms. It's a possibility that it only works with internal forms.

Comment: Hmm seems like that didn't work cross projects. Only internally, I'll do some other tests.

Comment: Please do. I am on the road to convert back to single project solution since  multiproject solutions lack in many things even shared resources!

Comment: There, an update was made. Although it is not as neat as the first solution it will work. :)

Comment: Well that really work. I should make a function since I have more forms to open such way. But I am still not clear by myself in order to make single project solution. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

In your original code, move the form declaration out to class (form) level:

```
Private ka As otherproject.frm_thatform = Nothing
```

Then check to see if it is Nothing or has been disposed, and recreate it as necessary:

```
If (ka Is Nothing) OrElse ka.IsDisposed Then
    ka = New otherproject.frm_thatform
    ka.Show(Me)
End If
If ka.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized Then
    ka.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
End If
ka.BringToFront()
```

Comment: That is interesting approach. For getting it to work I should call Show method without Me keyword.

Comment: That just tells the form who the "owner" is, linking them together.  Minimizing the owner also minimizes the "children".  It makes them work together like a unit.

Comment: Well strange, on second opening I get error message "Form that is already visible cannot be displayed as a modal dialog box. Set the form's visible property to false before calling Show." if is called with Me. Also "If IsNothing(ka)" don't work for me but "If ka Is Nothing" did work. VB2008, NET 2.0, win7/64.

Comment: Gotcha; sorry.  Move the Show() line up inside the If statement after creating the Form so that it is only called once.  Further attempts when the form is already open will simply call BringToFront().  You could also check the WindowState() before BringToFront() to un-minimize the window if necessary.  Not sure why IsNothing() doesn't work, not sure how far back in versions it goes.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options -

1. create a static/ shared form variable
  ```
  Shared form As SingletonformEx.Form1
  If form IsNot Nothing Then
      form.BringToFront()
  Else
      form = New SingletonformEx.Form1()
      form.Show()
  End If
  ```
2. Extend the form class and implement singleton pattern on it.
  ```
  Public Class SingletonForm Inherits Form     

      Private Shared m_instance As SingletonForm    

          Private Sub New()
          'InitializeComponent();
          End Sub

          Public Shared ReadOnly Property Instance() As SingletonForm
              Get
                  If m_instance Is Nothing Then
                      m_instance = New SingletonForm()
                  End If
                  m_instance.BringToFront()
                  Return m_instance
              End Get
          End Property
      End Class
  ```
  note: this is C# code converted to vb.net so i am not sure if this is perfect